# "Go to definition" doesn't work in GraphQL plugin

Tags: visual-studio-code, graphql

I'm facing an error "definition not found" on **MacOS** in **VSCode** in **GraphQL.vscode-graphql** plugin.
The plugin itself https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GraphQL.vscode-graphql

Plugin version is **v0.8.25**, VSCode version is **1.85.1**.

I have graphql.config.yml file at the root with "schema" and "documents" fields.
I have no custom configuration for that plugin.
I've relaunched VSCode about 20 times already (i hope caching have already happened).
I've deleted .vscode at the user directory (~./) (it was suggested somewhere)
I don't see any errors in the plugin output. It only says `{"type":"usage","messageType":"textDocument/definition","projectName":"project-name","fileName":"file:///path-to-the-file-qwe-qwe-qwe"}`

Autocomplete suggestions works as expected.

Did somebody face this problem before? What can I do / check myself more?

Answer (score 0):

According to this thread https://discord.com/channels/625400653321076807/863688262181453845/1197213459151081502 this bug is tracked.

All we can do now is to wait for an extension update.